# Android: Unable to align 3 views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have the following RelativeLayout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x_memtxtlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/x_memamtlay"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp">
        </TextView>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x_memamtlay"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_greybg"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x_memamt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/number_fill">
        </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I have to set EditText(@+id/x_memamtlay) visibility to gone/visible and 2nd TextView(@+id/x_memamt) visibility to gone/visible regularly in my activity based on some requirements.Either EditText or TextView will be visible at a time.

Problem is, in 1st TextView(@+id/x_memtxtlay),

when I set android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/x_memamtlay" : (to left of EditText)
[image]

But when I set android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/x_memamt" : (to left of 2nd TextView)
[image]

How can I adjust the layout so that 1st TextView aligns left to both EditText and 2nd TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this just a minor change in your code::

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x_memtxtlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="sdasdasd"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/x_memlay"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp">
        </TextView>
<FrameLayout  android:id="@+id/x_memlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x_memamtlay"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"


            android:visibility="gone">
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x_memamt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"

        </TextView>
</FrameLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Works but it made the layout more Creepy.The EdiText and 2nd TextView are expanded from 1st TextView to parent border.Pls have a look at this image - http://i.imgur.com/cMVFb.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working perfectly now.You saved me a lot of time.Actually, in the place of FrameLayout, I have tried LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, but it didnt worked. I didnt get the idea of using FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, where you are writing

```
      EditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

write

```
      EditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then you don't need to change your XML file.

Comment: Changing from Gone to Invisible didnt reflected any change in my layout.

Comment: don't set the visibility in the XML file.

Comment: see, you keep your textView aligned to either the EditText or the other TextView, don't set any of the view's visibility as GONE any time. This worked for me.

Comment: yes, it doesn't only in run-time and compile time. but according to me, it should work!

Comment: No Worries, Actually it worked, TextView aligned left to Edittext/2nd textview.(by setting layout_toRightOf="@+id/x_memtxtlay" to both Edittext and 2nd TextView - see Agarwal comment). BUT another PROBLEM ARISED,The EdiText and 2nd TextView are expanded from 1st TextView to parent border.Pls have a look at this image - i.imgur.com/cMVFb.jpg

Comment: That happens coz you are placing the TextView and EditText relative to the left side TextView. The change in visibility should have worked with you actually..

Comment: But changing from GONE to INVISIBLE didnt worked in my code.Anyways my issue got solved. And thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

XML has been kind of buggy with the last few updates. You need to type in the values to have what you want moved to where you want one by one.

Comment: The values are set at run-time so, he cannot set any layout values.